# UICollectionView with two columns, different cell sizes and one after the other

Tags: ios, swift

This is basically what I'm aiming for:

[image]

But my collection view looks like this:

[image]

Theres some kind of separator between the different rows.
I don't need them to resize with auto layout, it's a repeated pattern of 4 cells so I know the exact size of each one.

I'm using

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
```

for the size of each cell

And this is my flow layout:

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Vertical
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
```

How can approach that separation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do this using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. You have to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and create your own custom collection view layout.

Thankfully the great guys at Ray Wenderlich have done a tutorial on how to create a custom collection view layout that mimicks the layout of the Pinterest App. That layout does exactly that what you are trying to achieve.

[UICollectionView Custom Layout Tutorial: Pinterest](http://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Comment: You are the savior of my day dude